# Calling Upon An Enviromental Variable in a Path

Tags: python, environment-variables

```
import os

print "C:\Users\print os.environ['USERNAME']\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```

The basics of what I'm trying to do is to use the "os" module to use the USERNAME variable to fill in a directories path, Example below

```
"C:\Users\USER Name HERE\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```

`"USER Name HERE"` is the portion of the path which I'd like to be replaced with the os variable "USERNAME" aka `os.environ['USERNAME']`.

Essentially I'd like my file to be able to find out the current pc's username so it can change it's Path's accordingly.

ps. this command is alot easier to do in .bat file's xD, this is how I'd do this in a .bat file

```
SET USERNAME

:: Create new directory
md "C:\ProgramData\Data"   

COPY "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\DxAutoPackage\Win86\data\UserData" "C:\ProgramData\Data"
COPY "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\DxAutoPackage\Win86\system32.lnk"
```

Not sure if any one here knows too much about bat files but it might help make my question a little more clear :P

Anyway's any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: ok i thought i had it going but i was quite wrong about that sadly, here's the portion of the script im trying to get it to go into. srry for getting ahead of myself(first post)

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email import Encoders
import os

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = 'FakeEmail@hotmail.com'
msg['To'] = 'FakeEmail@hotmail.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'simple hotmail email'
message = '%USERNAME%'
msg.attach(MIMEText(message))
```

As you can probably see the message section of the script is what i'm trying edit with %USERNAME%

Edit: How would i go about adding the same variable to a a Path format which was formatted like this:

How would one go about add'ing the same variable to a script like this (mainly the path format)

```
import os
os.makedirs("C:\Users\'USERNAME'\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\StartMenu\Programs\Data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [os.path.expandvars](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars):

```
>>> import os
>>> print os.path.expandvars(r"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup")
C:\Users\falsetru\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Alternatively you can use os.environ + [str.format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.format):

```
>>> print r"C:\Users\{0[USERNAME]}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup".format(os.environ)
C:\Users\falsetru\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

---

**EDIT**

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email import Encoders
import os

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = 'FakeEmail@hotmail.com'
msg['To'] = 'FakeEmail@hotmail.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'simple hotmail email'
message = os.environ['USERNAME']
#message = os.path.expandvars('%USERNAME%') # alternative
msg.attach(MIMEText(message))
```

Comment: Also, note the use of raw strings `r"..."` to make the backslashes much easier to work with.

Comment: im working on getting it working right now, i'm a little confused by the method you used to import the os module (just a bit new) 

Let's just say i was trying to get the username to be placed in a sentence like so.

import os.path.expandvars
"hey guys i would like to go to the %USERNAME%"

would this work ?, i just want to make sure i can use this for other purposes like placing the username in an email to identify which server it came from.

Comment: i'm going to continue to dissect this till i get it working, i thank you for the assistance whatever the out come may be!

Comment: K thank's for editing your post i'm almost positive i'll be able to figure it out now :)

Comment: K got it working and btw great answer it was really handy the only thing that confused me was that i couldn't really tell if os.path was a completely different module then os xD (im probaly just being noob but lol) here's the final script:
~
import os.path
message = 'os.path.expandvars(%USERNAME%)'
~
Alternatively: 
import os.path
message = 'os.path.expandvars({0[USERNAME]})'
~
didn't test that one but that should work too :P
:P

Comment: `os.path` module is submodule of `os` module. `os.path` contains functions related to path manipulation.

Comment: i really feel like i should have just posted my script right off the bat xD , i'm going to take a break but im going to keep trying till i get this :P